# Table row selection, but text in it doesn't want to be selected

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery table with lots of row and I did the row selection work also, but I don't want the cell value to be selected if I drag select the row. How do I work with selecting the able row and not the values by drag select?

Answer (score 2):

For most browsers, you should add a class to the table (e.g. 'selecting') and have the following CSS declaration:

```
.selecting {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

For IE, however, you should subscribe to the **selectstart** and **dragstart** events and cancel them through javascript.

Comment: Thanks, so can we give this for the whole table. or the div that i use

Comment: it should be applied to the area that you don't want to be selected

Comment: thats of great help and let me implement and let you know